# MiKTeX - Compile Error during Installation

Tags: errors, miktex

I have been trying to install MiKTeX on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, I have been following the instructions from http://miktex.org/howto/build-unx. After several obstacles and installing the mentioned libraries, I successfully ran the command `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"`. Now, I'm stuck at the second step `make`, I'm getting the following error:

```
$ make
[  0%] Built target bintoc
[  0%] Built target j2000
[  0%] Built target web-n
[  0%] Building CXX object Libraries/3rd/graphite2/CMakeFiles/MiKTeX209-graphite2.dir/source/src/direct_machine.cpp.o
In file included from ~/Downloads/miktex-2.9-2016-02-26/Libraries/3rd/graphite2/source/src/direct_machine.cpp:42:0: ~/Downloads/miktex-2.9-2016-02-26/Libraries/3rd/graphite2/source/src/inc/Machine.h:36:22: fatal error: inc/Main.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [Libraries/3rd/graphite2/CMakeFiles/MiKTeX209-graphite2.dir/source/src/direct_machine.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Libraries/3rd/graphite2/CMakeFiles/MiKTeX209-graphite2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can someone please assist me how to proceed and where to look for errors?

Comment: [Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  MikTeX is the mainly intended for Windows (probably why you had obstacles installing it).  The standard distribution for Linux is TeXLive which can be installed with `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`.

Comment: @JP-Ellis I've been using MiKTeX on Windows for over 2 years, hence wanted to run the same on linux machine as I'm pretty comfortable with it. Thanks anyways!

Comment: As far as the output generated, MikTeX and TeXLive are identical.  That is, `pdflatex` is (essentially) the same for both.  The only difference is the interface to update/install packages... and even that is all handled by `apt-get` (unless you install TeXLive manually, which I would recommend but is not strictly necessary).

Comment: I wouldn't do it. The differences between texlive and miktex are rather small and it is imho not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to compile miktex for linux. The differences between texlive and miktex are rather small and it is imho not worth the trouble.

Comment: The solution is that I didn't go for troubleshooting on Linux. I'm using texlive on Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install libgraphite2*
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add some extra information and expand your answer a little bit?